# How to make this query start digits with ORMLite querybuilder?

Tags: sql, sqlite, ormlite

I got 2 problems.

1. is this query right to get rows start with digits?

   `select * from [tables] where [column] like '[0-9]%'`
2. How to makes it to `queryBuilder` of `ormlite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to the end of several attempts.

1. Query that begin with digit

   `SELECT * FROM [tables] WHERE [column] >= '0' AND [column] <= '9'`

   with regex:

   `SELECT * FROM [tables] WHERE [column] REGEXP '[0-9]+'`
2. Use the GenericRawResults, if you want to use regular expressions to query in ORMLite.
   Examples are as follows.

   ```
   GenericRawResults<T> rawResults = getYourDao().queryRaw(
       "SELECT * FROM " + [tables] + " WHERE " + [column] + " REGEXP '[0-9]+'",
       getYourDao().getRawRowMapper(), String...params);
   List<T> dataList = rawResults.getResults();
   ```

Comment: Will the first one will work if the column is not numerical?  If the string is, for example, "1 dog" will it work?

Comment: Yes, it works. First work with '1 dog'. But query with regexp doesn't work :(

Comment: You could try '^[0-9]' as the regexp.

Comment: @fbiazi When I test it with android sqlite, it doesn't work correctly. But at regex tester, it works. I don't know what is problem.